# How to make filter:grayscale without one element(CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to make the whole site gray(`filter: grayscale(1)`) since some events, but in my site there is a monaco-editor, I don't want to lose the code highlight. The HTML rendered DOM like:

```html
<div class="monaco-editor">
  <div class="viewer-line">
     <span class="random-code1">Hello</span>
     <span class="random-code2">World</span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

and the site DOM like:

```html
<body>
  <section></section>
  <section>{code_editor}</section>
</body>
```

I used the `filter: grayscale(1)` in CSS file like:

```
*:not(.monaco-editor) {
   filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

But it doesn't work since the filtered element can't be recovered.

I also tried `mix-blend-mode` but it seems the same.

So how to make the site gray without one element in CSS?

The meaning of whole site gray is:

```
body {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

What I want is:

```
body {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.monaco-editor {
  // rendered color as usual
  // filter: grayscale(0); // not working well
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this question but when you write "make the site gray" you mean gray background and black text? And filter won't act on text nodes nor background-color.

Comment: You mean the body? You can do that with a simple tag: <body style="background-color:#CCCCCC;"> this will bring a grey scale of CCCCCC value into your page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho Hi, I update my description

Comment: @A.Meshu update now

Comment: @Paulie_D I edit it!

Comment: @SkyAo even after you edit your question i can't understand what is the desired result. Can you add picture?

Comment: When you select everything with *, this code *:not(.monaco-editor) will not select monaco editor but it will select children, so probably you shouldn't do this way. Please paste the code so we can help you achieve desired result.